# Error initializing IPython notebook (bug)

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've got the following error over the terminal shell when Ipython notebook starts:

> [IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
>
> [IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--profile-dir'

In the browser Ipython tries to restart continuosly and the same message is repeated in the terminal. Please help me!